# jQuery to hide fields with no value in submitted address through form with method=get , doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the follow to a form with `method="get"` and other several dropdown menus. When I submit the form, because I do not want a huge address, I try to leave only the fields that are not empty.

Currently if I choose some of them, the result is disabling all, even the dropdown menus that I have selected a value.

What am I missing here?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#apliforma').submit(function () {
        $(this).find('select').not(":selected").prop('disabled', true);
        return true;
    });
});
```

---

```
   <select class="form-control" name="kivikafrom" id="from">
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="1000">1000 cc</option>
                <option value="1200">1200 cc</option>
                <option value="1400">1400 cc</option>
                <option value="1600">1600 cc</option>                   
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your dropdowns have a default or non-selected value of `""`, this should work:

```
$(this).find('select').filter(function() {
    return this.value == ''; 
}).prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think that there is no requirement to disable other select box option.

you can get only selected value by

```
var selected_value = $("#from").val();
if(select_value != ''){
  /* write code for what ever you want */
}
```

As per knowledge, there is not required extra effort to disable all other option, but when you submit your form then it will send  only select option from select box in your params. All other unselected option will not be sent in params.